# How to make Android device visible for BLE scan

Tags: android, bluetooth, device, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing an app where i want to create "history of meetings" between app users. I want to make it work on BLE. I already have working BLE devices scanning code which i have tested on iBeacons. Now i want to make my second phone visible for scanning but i can't find any code to make it visible programmatically.

@I have seen that peripherial mode is added in Android L. Isn't there any way to make it work on 4.3?